# Remove custom widgets from Page Builder area in Big Commerce

Tags: widget, bigcommerce

I've been experimenting with creating custom widgets but I'm not sure how I remove custom widgets in the Page Builder area in Big Commerce? I've successfully [deleted the widget](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-content/widgets/widget#delete-a-widget) and [deleted the placement](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-content/widgets/placement#delete-a-placement) via the APIs and cannot see them (via the APIs) but I still see them in the Page Builder (even when clearing the browser cache), i.e.

[image: Big Commerce Page Builder - custom widgets]

Answer (score 0):

Ok further reading has led me to understand that the custom widgets in the page builder (as I referred to them in the question) are actually custom widget templates. So [deleting them is as the API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-content/widgets/widget-template#delete-a-widget-template)